# Crash: constraint is nil in viewController2 while rotating on viewController1

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, viewcontroller

I am calling this code in viewController2:

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

     if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {

        rotatedBool = true

        tableViewConstraint.constant = -12

     } else {

        rotatedBool = false

       tableViewConstraint.constant = 21

    }

}
```

However, if I rotate the app from another view prior to having loaded this view (viewController2), I get a crash.
"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value." (tableViewConstraint)

I dont understand why this code (in viewController2) gets called from another view.

Does anyone has an idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: Could it be that your constraint only exists in one size class and that when your screen is rotated the constraint is not defined for that size class and thus the outlet is nil?

Comment: No, the constraint itself is fine. The issue is actually quite strange, for instance, I have initialised a variable boolean set to false that when the viewWillAppear, will be set to true; then added in the codes above "if UIDevice.currentDevice...", and it then keeps these codes to be executed until the view has loaded and ready to appear.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be called without calling the `ViewController2` I replicated your problem and, as expected, nothing was called inside the `ViewController2`

You must have other codes that call it